# React Native - react-redux PropTypes error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

In my React Native project `react: 16.8.3 => 16.8.3 - react-native: ^0.59.5 => 0.59.10`

I updated the `react-redux` for using the hooks from the version `5.xx` to `7.1.3` and since the update I'm getting an error with prop-types dependency.

> error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module
>   '../utils/PropTypes' from
>   '/node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/Provider.js': The
>   module '../utils/PropTypes' could not be found from
>   '/node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/Provider.js'.

Indeed, none of these files exist:I already installed the prop-types dependency manually and it does not help me.

Comment: How did you manually install the propTypes dep?  If you do `npm list | grep propTypes`  what is the output?

Comment: ok what is that result.  Sorry wasn't sure about the casing

Comment: Having the same problem: @ruby_newbie I'm pretty sure what you're seeing is the sub deps of pother packages on prop-types. This is a single line of mine: `│ └── prop-types@15.7.2 deduped`

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you've already got propTypes there. What you can try, and what worked for me is doing **both** of the following.

**Step 1**: `npm ci` this will remove `node_modules` and reinstall with the correct 'acceptable' deps from your `packages.json`
Then you'll need to get clear the *React Native packager cache*.

**Step 2:**

#### RN with Expo

With Expo, this can be done either of two ways:

1. Run `npm start` (which is `expo start`) and in the same terminal press `Shift + r` which will reset cache and restart bundler
2. Use `expo start --clear` which will clear the expo cache

#### React Native w/o expo

This should work, the typical watchmen reset:

- `npm start -- --reset-cache`
- or if that doesn't work, try the typical:

  - `watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-*`
  - (something like this, depends on your machine)

Answer (score 0):

This helped to me:
`npm start -- --reset-cache`